# Joomla valaddthis-plugin css

Tags: css, joomla

I use valaddthis on joomla 1.5.25 but i have a problem with its css. I spotted with firebug that the problem is margin-top which should be altered to 215px for my webpage. Its css derives from widget76.css which is imported for the iframe utility from http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/widget76.css address. How can i add this change?
    `#at16p
    {
        margin-top: 215px !important;
    }`

This is all i need.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain with screenshot with firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem with overriding css of addthis.com.
You have to create one division(or existing) before addthis widget, give some id(myid) to that division and this was you can override css property.

```
#myid at16p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

I think this was you can change default css of addthis widget. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, i was changing css on valladdthis module not plugin while using the plugin. I put the css change i mentioned before and worked smoothly. Thanx again.